# A function that compare if there is duplicate numbers in a array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to create a function that compares duplicate numbers in an array, and if there are duplicate numbers, I return these numbers in an array.

That's what I did, but I'm struggling.

```
function solution(array) {
    var a = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i] === 1) {
            a.push(array[i]);
        }
    }
    return a;
}

alert(solution([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1]));




solution([2, 1, 1, 2, 2]); //Should return [1, 2, 2]. Because 2, 1 are original documents and 1, 2, 2 - are copies
```

Comment: "Should return [1, 2, 2]" - Why 2 occurs two times?

Comment: The code you are showing goes through the array and finds all the values that are === 1. That's not what you want to do, is it?  why do you compare to number one?

Comment: because i don't know how to compare the current loop with the past numbers, so i put i placeholder to test.. @bjelli

Comment: _"Should return [1, 2, 2]."_ - Why not `[2, 1, 2]` or `[2, 2, 1]`, given that 2 is the first number in the array that has a duplicate? Have you tried a nested for loop?

Answer (score 3):

`indexOf` returns the index of the first occurrence of the element. `filter` applies a function once to each element of the array and returns a new array of all the elements where the function returns `true`.

```
function solution(array) {
    return array.filter(function(value, index) {
        return array.indexOf(value) < index;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have two arrays: one with the original numbers, and one with the result, where you collect the duplicate numbers.

You are looping over the original array. that is a good start.

array[i] is the current number of the original array.

How can you find out if it is has already occured before, and is therefore duplicate? that's the next step in your algorithm that you have to figure out.

you probably need another loop, or another array, and probably an if somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

A slightly faster version of openorclose's answer:

```
function solution(array) {
   return array.filter(function(value, index) {
      return array.indexOf(value, index + 1) > -1;
   });
}
```